# Python Static Variable List __del__

Tags: python, list, methods, static-variables, del

I'm trying to create a class using a static List, which collects all new instances of an object class. The problem I'm facing, seems like as soon as i try to use a list the same way as for example an integer, i can't use the magic marker `__del__` anymore.

My Example:

```
class MyClass(object):  

    count = 0
    #instances = []

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        MyClass.count += 1
        #MyClass.instances.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.__repr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "a: " + str(self.a) + ", b: " + str(self.b)

    def __del__(self):
        MyClass.count -= 1
        #MyClass.instances.remove(self)

A = MyClass(1,'abc')
B = MyClass(2,'def')
print MyClass.count
del B
print MyClass.count
```

With comments I get the correct answer:

```
2
1
```

But without the comments - including now the static object list MyClass.instances I get the wrong answer:

```
2
2
```

It seems like MyClass can't reach its `__del__` method anymore! How Come?

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__),

```
del x doesn’t directly call x.__del__() — the former decrements the reference
count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s reference count
reaches zero.
```

When you uncomment,

```
instances = []
...
...
MyClass.instances.append(self)
```

You are storing a reference to the current Object in the `MyClass.instances`. That means, the reference count is internally incremented by 1. That is why `__del__` is not getting called immediately.

To resolve this problem, explicitly remove the item from the list like this

```
MyClass.instances.remove(B)
del B
```

Now it will print

```
2
1
```

as expected.

There is one more way to fix this problem. That is to use `weakref`. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html),

> A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive:
>   when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references,
>   garbage collection is free to destroy the referent and reuse its
>   memory for something else. A primary use for weak references is to
>   implement caches or mappings holding large objects, where it’s desired
>   that a large object not be kept alive solely because it appears in a
>   cache or mapping.

So, having a `weakref` will not postpone object's deletion. With `weakref`, this can be fixed like this

```
MyClass.instances.append(weakref.ref(self))
...
...
# MyClass.instances.remove(weakref.ref(self))
MyClass.instances = [w_ref for w_ref in MyClass.instances if w_ref() is None]
```

Instead of using `remove` method, we can call each of the `weakref` objects and if they return `None`, they are already dead. So, we filter them out with the list comprehension.

So, now, when you say `del B`, even though `weakref`s exist for `B`, it will call `__del__` (unless you have made some other variable point to the same object, like by doing an assigment).

Answer (score 1):

From to http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization I quote (paragraph in gray after `object.__del__`):

> `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the reference count for x by one, and the latter is only called when x‘s reference count reaches zero.

Here you call `del B` but there is still an instance of B in MyClass.instances, so that B is still referenced and hence not destroyed, so that the `__del__` function is not called. 
If you call directly `B.__del__()`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

`__del__` is only called when no more instances are left.

You should consider putting only weak refs into the `MyClass.instances` list.

This can be achieved with `import weakref` and then

- either using a `WeakSet` for the list
- or putting `weakref.ref(self)` into the list.

`__del__` is automatically called whenever the last "strict" reference is removed. The weakrefs disappear automatically.

But be aware that there are some caveats on `__del__` mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

Answer (score 0):

`__del__` is used when the garbage collector remove an object from the memory. If you add your object to MyClass.instances then the object is marked as "used" and the garbage collector will never try to remove it. And so `__del__` is never called.

You'd better use an explicit function (MyClass.del_element()) because you can't really predict when `__del__` will be called (even if you don't add it to a list).